# set default Google Map location

Tags: dictionary, default

We are rolling out a multisite wordpress app. Some of our users are in Africa. Some in various of the US. Each will be given a subsite in the multisite network.

On each subsite, we have a page showing the member local support groups affiliated with them using Google map. We would like to open the map that is pertinent to our user. If the user is in Africa, then the map will by default open Africa. And if the user is in Missouri, the page will by default open up in MO.

How to achieve that?

Jing